# F-String in mail python

Tags: python, f-string

when I use f-string to print supplier names, I use this code:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(f'{df_supplier_number["SUPPLIER NAME"][i]}')
```

The result looks like this:

```
supplier 1
supplier 2
supplier 3
supplier 4
supplier 5
...
```

But when using this method to write an email, I does not work.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.Subject = f'{df_supplier_number["SUPPLIER NAME"][i]}' + "_test"
    mail.To = "test@mail.com"
    mail.HTMLBody = r"""
    Hallo,<br><br>
    test """f"{df_supplier_number[i]}"r""" erstellen:<br><br>
    Mit dem Text:<br>
    test1 by """f"{df_supplier_number[i]}"r""".<br>
    Settlement Date Range: 01. November 2020 to 31. October 2021.<br><br>
    Und dem Betrag:<br>
    """f'{round(df_supplier_number[i],2)}'r""" € (wie in der angehängten Excel-Datei zu erkennen).<br><br>
    test
    """
    mail.Attachments.Add(os.getcwd()+ "\\" + f'{df_number[i]}'"_test.xlsx")
  
    mail.Send()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `f` goes before the quotes, like `rf"""Hallo, ... {df_supplier}"""`

Comment: I would strongly recommend using a real templating library like Jinja2 for something like this.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for your help. Your solution works fine in my first example. Using it in mail, I get an error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly what error you get, including the full traceback if there is one. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: As an aside, `print(f'{df_supplier_number["SUPPLIER NAME"][i]}')` is just a really clumsy way to say `print(str(df_supplier_number["SUPPLIER NAME"][i]))` where the `str()` is also superfluous if the variable is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have gone wild with r-string and f-string. I placed a single pair at the beginning of the HTMLBODY portion and the removed addition r,f, & potentially unneeded ". Please try the below out and see if it works for you. I made a random list of numbers to test out and everything seems to be working on my end.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.Subject = f'{df_supplier_number["SUPPLIER NAME"][i]}' + "_test"
    mail.To = "test@mail.com"
    mail.HTMLBody = rf"""
        Hallo,<br><br>
        test "{df_supplier_number[i]}" erstellen:<br><br>
        Mit dem Text:<br>
        test1 by "{df_supplier_number[i]}".<br>
        Settlement Date Range: 01. November 2020 to 31. October 2021.<br><br>
        Und dem Betrag:<br>
        '{round(df_supplier_number[i],2)}'€ (wie in der angehängten Excel-Datei     
zu erkennen).<br><br>
test
"""
mail.Attachments.Add(os.getcwd()+ "\\" + f'{df_number[i]}'"_test.xlsx")

mail.Send()
```